# Moving rows in a dataframe considering a condition over them in R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a little question in R. I have a dataframe in R named `DF`. It has 10 rows. First column is an ID and the rest columns show a rate that can be A, B, C, D, E or F (I add `dput()` version of `DF` in the final part). `DF` looks like this:

```
   ID M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 M9 M10
1  001  A  B  C  D  E  F  F  F  G   G
2  002  E  E  E  F  F  F  F  F  G   G
3  003  C  D  E  F  F  G  G  G  G   G
4  004  A  C  C  C  D  E  F  G  G   G
5  005  B  B  B  B  B  C  D  E  F   G
6  006  B  B  B  B  B  C  C  D  E   F
7  007  A  A  A  B  C  D  E  E  E   F
8  008  A  B  B  B  C  C  D  E  F   F
9  009  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F  F   F
10 010  A  A  A  A  B  C  D  E  F   G
11 011  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B  B   B
```

For example, for first row I have `F` in column `M6`. When a `F` is present in a row, then all the information after `F`(including this) should be moved to the column `M1` and the information that wasn't complete due to the move should be filled with `NA`. I was trying to make this but I can't get the wished result. I don't know if I can apply `ifelse` in rows to identify first `F` and the move this and their information to the column `M1`. I would like to get something like this:

```
    ID M1   M2   M3   M4   M5   M6   M7   M8   M9  M10
1  001  F    F    F    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  002  F    F    F    F    F    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  003  F    F    G    G    G    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  004  F    G    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  005  F    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  006  F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
7  007  F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
8  008  F    F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
9  009  F    F    F    F    F    F    F    F    F    F
10 010  F    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
11 011  B    B    B    B    B    B    B    B    B    B
```

I tried creating a new data frame only with `NA` but it is complex to insert a condition for rows to identify first ocuurence of `F` and then move information in the row to column `M1`. The `dput()` version of `DF` is the next:

**EDITED**

```
structure(list(ID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", 
"007", "008", "009", "010", "011"), M1 = c("A", "E", "C", "A", 
"B", "B", "A", "A", "F", "A", "B"), M2 = c("B", "E", "D", "C", 
"B", "B", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B"), M3 = c("C", "E", "E", "C", 
"B", "B", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B"), M4 = c("D", "F", "F", "C", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "F", "A", "B"), M5 = c("E", "F", "F", "D", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "F", "B", "B"), M6 = c("F", "F", "G", "E", 
"C", "C", "D", "C", "F", "C", "B"), M7 = c("F", "F", "G", "F", 
"D", "C", "E", "D", "F", "D", "B"), M8 = c("F", "F", "G", "G", 
"E", "D", "E", "E", "F", "E", "B"), M9 = c("G", "G", "G", "G", 
"F", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "B"), M10 = c("G", "G", "G", "G", 
"G", "F", "F", "F", "F", "G", "B")), .Names = c("ID", "M1", "M2", 
"M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", "M9", "M10"), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the quickest method, using `apply`, but it works:

```
dat[-1] <- t(apply(
  dat[-1],
  1,
  function(x) {
    if("F" %in% x) {
      sel <- x[match("F",x):length(x)] 
      c(sel, rep(NA,length(x)-length(sel)) )
    } else
    x
  }
))

#    ID M1   M2   M3   M4   M5   M6   M7   M8   M9  M10
#1  001  F    F    F    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2  002  F    F    F    F    F    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3  003  F    F    G    G    G    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4  004  F    G    G    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#5  005  F    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6  006  F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#7  007  F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#8  008  F    F <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#9  009  F    F    F    F    F    F    F    F    F    F
#10 010  F    G <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#11 011  B    B    B    B    B    B    B    B    B    B
```

Comment: Thanks for your help dear @thelatemail but I found something interesting. I made an edit and when I add a row where there is not `F` inside I got this error: `Error in match("F", x):length(x) : NA/NaN argument `. Your solution is fast and optimal but it is possible to adjust your solution to this case.